# Transfer value from code behind in xaml page to change expander foreground

Tags: c#, xaml, expander

```
<Expander x:Name="exp" 
          IsExpanded="True"
          Background= "White"
          Foreground="Black">
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </Expander.Header>
        <ItemsPresenter />
</Expander>
```

I want to change Foreground value from c# code behind base on a if condition.. how do i transfer the value from code behind to access it in xaml page?

Comment: Try `exp.Foreground`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody needs this in the future, i have done it using triggers:

```
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Result}" Value="F">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold" />
            </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

This will change the entire data grid row foreground when the Result = "F".

Answer (score 0):

Code Behind will be

```
exp.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red);
```

or

```
exp.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
```

or

```
exp.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0);
```

or

```
exp.Foreground = System.Windows.SystemColors.ControlLightColor;
```

Comment: but how do i declare my expander in code behind, because it doesn't recognizes it?   "The name 'exp' does not exist in the current context"